# gdalinfo retrieve WMS layer abstract

Tags: gdal, wms, gdalinfo

When using gdalinfo on WMS, abstract aren't returned, is there a way to get them ? I only get subdataset name and title.

For example, for the first layer I get "*DESC=Courbes de niveau*", I'm trying to get something like "*Abstract=Le produit « Courbes de niveau » est un modèle numérique de terrain sous forme de courbes de même altitude, appelées aussi « isoplèthes d’altitude », ou plus techniquement « isohypses ». Ces courbes permettent la description du relief français.*". (see WMS below).

**WMS :** "*[https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities*"](https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities*%22)

**gdalinfo response :**

```
Driver: WMS/OGC Web Map Service
Files: none associated
Size is 512, 512
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATION.CONTOUR.LINE&CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-7054596.823974940,-2448678.407635810,6225638.766865120,6676690.825125160
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=Courbes de niveau
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE&CRS=IGNF:WGS84G&BBOX=-64.000000000,-23.000000000,168.000000000,52.000000000
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=MNT BDAlti V1
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES&CRS=IGNF:WGS84G&BBOX=-62.952807692,-13.007809422,45.304315325,51.105279680
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=Modèle Numérique de Terrain issu du RGEALTI
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES.MNS&CRS=IGNF:WGS84G&BBOX=-63.196777591,-21.433778409,55.863926027,51.220046622
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=Modèle numérique de surface
  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES.MNS.SHADOW&CRS=IGNF:WGS84G&BBOX=-63.196777591,-21.433778409,55.863926027,51.220046622
  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=Estompage appliqué au Modèle Numérique de Surface
  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.SHADOW&CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-7033940.732188000,-2440465.299263510,6221468.491008040,6607472.687869718
  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=Estompage
  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.SRTM3&CRS=IGNF:WGS84G&BBOX=-180.000416667,-56.000416667,180.000416667,61.000416667
  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=MNT SRTM3
  SUBDATASET_8_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.THRESHOLD&CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-573348.000000000,5060429.000000000,1065388.000000000,6638834.000000000
  SUBDATASET_8_DESC=Seuils de pente pour l'agriculture
  SUBDATASET_9_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES.QUALITY&CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-7054596.823974940,-2448678.407635810,6225638.766865120,6676690.825125160
  SUBDATASET_9_DESC=Masque de source du RGE Alti
  SUBDATASET_10_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.SLOPES.MOUNTAIN&CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-7031094.000000000,-2456939.000000000,6234093.000000000,6638834.000000000
  SUBDATASET_10_DESC=Carte des pentes
  SUBDATASET_11_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_FXX_LAMB93_WMS&CRS=IGNF:LAMB93&BBOX=89999.500000000,6046000.500000000,1242999.500000000,7115000.500000000
  SUBDATASET_11_DESC=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_FXX_LAMB93_WMS1
  SUBDATASET_12_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_GLP_WGS84UTM20_WMS&CRS=IGNF:UTM20W84GUAD&BBOX=-500.000000000,-806362.500000000,1036762.500000000,12000500.000000000
  SUBDATASET_12_DESC=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_GLP_WGS84UTM20_WMS20200706
  SUBDATASET_13_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_GUF_UTM22RGFG95_WMS&CRS=IGNF:UTM22RGFG95&BBOX=95999.500000000,230000.500000000,432999.500000000,640000.500000000
  SUBDATASET_13_DESC=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_GUF_UTM22RGFG95_WMS2
  SUBDATASET_14_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_MTQ_WGS84UTM20_WMS&CRS=IGNF:UTM20W84MART&BBOX=689999.499999701,1591000.499999883,736999.499999158,1646000.499999969
  SUBDATASET_14_DESC=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_MTQ_WGS84UTM20_WMS20160317
  SUBDATASET_15_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_MYT_RGM04UTM38S_WMS&CRS=IGNF:RGM04UTM38S&BBOX=496999.500000000,8562000.500000000,532999.500000000,8604000.500000000
  SUBDATASET_15_DESC=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_MYT_RGM04UTM38S_WMS_20151001
  SUBDATASET_16_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_REU_RGR92UTM40S_WMS&CRS=IGNF:RGR92UTM40S&BBOX=312999.500000000,7633000.500000000,379999.500000000,7694000.500000000
  SUBDATASET_16_DESC=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_REU_RGR92UTM40S_WMS
  SUBDATASET_17_NAME=WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_SPM_RGSPM06U21_WMS&CRS=IGNF:RGSPM06U21&BBOX=535999.500000000,5177000.500000000,569999.500000000,5222000.500000000
  SUBDATASET_17_DESC=RGEALTI-MNT_PYR-ZIP_SPM_RGSPM06U21_WMS_20170617
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

I also tried gdal_translate to creating a [service description file](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/gdal-tools.html#creating-a-service-description-file), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the GDAL raster data model from https://gdal.org/user/raster_data_model.html.

For GDAL WMS is a datasource with one or more subdatasets.

> The SUBDATASETS domain holds a list of child datasets. Normally this
> is used to provide pointers to a list of images stored within a single
> multi image file.
>
> The value of the _NAME is the string that can be passed to GDALOpen()
> to access the file. The _DESC value is intended to be a more user
> friendly string that can be displayed to the user in a selector.

So the NAME of a WMS layer is used as _NAME, and the TITLE of the WMS layer is used for _DESC. There is no place to show the abstract. User need to read the abstract directly from the native GetCapabilities response of the WMS server.